# How to make the footskip zero in the following setting?

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr

How to make the footskip zero in the following setting?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, please provide an at least compilable, or even better minimum working example. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I guess that you want to decrease the bottom margin?

With an up-to-date KOMA-Script version you could set `usegeometry` as class option. Then you can load `geometry` and set either `footskip=0pt` or option `nofoot`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,
  usegeometry% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[footskip=0pt]{geometry}% <- added
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
The footskip is \the\footskip.

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But this does not change the size of the bottom margin. So I guess you want to do something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,
  usegeometry% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nofoot,
  bottom=2cm% <-
]{geometry}% <- added
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}

The footskip is \the\footskip.

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]